# Jar file - adding images to jar file

Tags: java, image, jar

So i had issues with my Jar file not finding my images that i kept in my graphics folder so i went and copy/pasted them into my UI folder where the classes that need them are as such:
[image]

although this looks rly bad the earthmap image now works but the loading8.gif stil wont work. it says it cant find the file.
here is the code:

```
public LoadingLabel(){
      loadingIcon  = new ImageIcon(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("loading8.gif")));
    }
```

why wont it find the file? how do i fix it ?

Comment: What build tool are you using? Maven? Gradle?

Comment: Just the normal intellij IDE

Answer (score -1):

Check with the path of the images. Hope the image path is properly configured. if you are copying the images at oneplace and the path is pointed to a different location then you see this kind of issues.